Extending homeomorphisms on closure spaces
Let $C$ be an infinite $T_1$ closure space, which is not a topological space. Suppose $C$ has the exchange property: for $x,y\in C$ and $A\subseteq C$
$$
\big( x\notin\overline{A}, \hspace{4mm} x\in \overline{A\cup\{y\}} \big) \Rightarrow y\in\overline{A\cup\{x\}}
$$

Question: What extra hypothesis (as weak as possible) do we need on $C$ so that every homeomorphism between closed subsets of $C$ extends to a homeomorphism on $C$?

As an example, suppose there exists a function $^*$ on subsets of $C$ satisfying

(1) $C^* = \emptyset$ and $\emptyset^*=C$
(2) $A^*$ is closed for all $A\subset C$
(3) $(A^*)^* = \overline{A}$ for all $A\subset C$ (involution on closed sets)
(4) $\overline{A}\cap A^* = \emptyset$ and $\overline{A\cup A^*} = C$ for all $A\subset C$
(5.a) if $A, B\subseteq C$ are homeomorphic, then so are $A^*$ and $B^*$. (5.b) Moreover, the glued map $A\cup A^* \to B\cup B^*$ can always be extended to a homeomorphism $C\to C$.

then every homeomorphism between closed subsets has an extension. (Note: There exists closure spaces that satisfy all bullet points but 5.b, in which homeomorphism extension fails.)
I am looking for weaker assumptions.

Definitions: Verbatim similar to that of topological spaces; included to avoid ambiguities (if there should be any).
$C$ is $T_1$ if each singleton $\{x\}\subset C$ is a closed set.
A function $f:C\to C$ is a homeomorphism if $f$ is bijective and $f(\overline{A})=\overline{f(A)}$ for each $A\subseteq C$. A homeomorphism $\phi:B_1\to B_2$ between two closed subsets $B_1,B_2\subset C$ is said to extend to $C$ if there exists a homeomorphism $\tilde{\phi}:C\to C$ such that $\tilde{\phi}(x)=\phi(x)$ for all $x\in B_1$.
